# What is a 2-fraction?

Tags: continued-fractions

I am working with a 4-term recurrence relation coming from the application of the Frobenius method on a ODE, in particular I am studying the convergence of the resulting series. Trying to find out a method to find conditions that impose convergence on the series I came across [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0377042783900195) which uses 2-fractions. They seem to be a generalization of continued fractions, but I cannot find anything on the internet on this subject.

What is a 2-fraction? And how do I deal with it?

Comment: The paper defined it in the first page.

Comment: @user10354138 I understand that, but I do not understand the definition and the notation: what is the  matrix with a hole? How do I rewrite it as an explicit formula in order to use it?

Comment: See [Levrie (1994)](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82409798.pdf). The method to determine the $n$th approximant is detailed in $(3)$. If you are interested in further details, refer to [Cusick (1977)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242921632_The_Szekers_Multidimensional_Continued_Fraction), [de Bruin (2007)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11075-007-9115-1), and page 23 of [Schmidt (2000)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bd24/383e0f851f9ae7c97ca1c7029647552bc8f8.pdf)

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Thanks I will study ithe references you provided